# Create subject-wise timepoints for date column in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that contains a column for the subject id and a column containing information about the date. I want to create a third variable that indicates the time order of the dates for each subject. An example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,1,2,2,3,3,3],
                   'Date':[20191219,
                           20191220,
                           20191220,
                           20191219,
                           20191219,
                           20191220,
                           20191221]})
```

which gives you:

```
   ID      Date
0   1  20191219
1   1  20191220
2   2  20191220
3   2  20191219
4   3  20191219
5   3  20191220
6   3  20191221
```

Add a third variable *t* so that you get:

```
   ID      Date  t
0   1  20191219  0
1   1  20191220  1
2   2  20191220  1
3   2  20191219  0
4   3  20191219  0
5   3  20191220  1
6   3  20191221  2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After clarification, I think you need `groupby.cumcount()` method, but before that you need to sort values by `ID`, and `Date` and drop any duplicates:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4],
                   'Foo':['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h'],
                   'Date':[20191219,
                           20191219,
                           20191220,
                           20191219,
                           20191219,
                           20191220,
                           20191221,
                           20191222]})

df['t'] = df.sort_values(['ID', 'Date']).drop_duplicates(['ID', 'Date']).groupby('ID').cumcount()
df['t'] = df['t'].fillna(method='ffill').astype(int)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   ID Foo      Date  t
0   1   a  20191219  0
1   1   b  20191219  0
2   2   c  20191220  1
3   2   d  20191219  0
4   3   e  20191219  0
5   3   f  20191220  1
6   3   g  20191221  2
7   4   h  20191222  0
```

Comment: This doesn't work. The timepoint variable t contains increasing numbers as you add more subjects to the data frame. For example, if you add a fourth subject with the date 20191222 to the data frame, you get a timepoint 3 for that subject. It should be labeld with a 0.

Comment: @JohannesWiesner with `df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4], 'Date':[20191219, 20191220, 20191220, 20191219, 20191219, 20191220, 20191221, 20191222]})` I get column `t = [0 1 1 0 0 1 2 3]`. Is it wrong?

Comment: Yes, because subject 4 should get a 0 for its first and only date. Sorry if my question should have been misleading.

Comment: This doesn't work either. Change the second date for the first subject to 20191219 (so both dates for subject one are the same) and you will get a 1 for that row (but there should be a 0, since it is the same date for the same subject).

Comment: This doesn't work in combination when the data frame contains also a column with unique values in each row. E.g., when you add the column `'Foo':['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h']` to the data frame, the method fails, probably because the method contains `drop_duplicates`. My original data frame contains such a column.